# WordPress W3 Total Cache Plugin not combining CSS & JS

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

Can anyone help me understand why W3 Total Cache Plugin for WordPress on [this website](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.theportlandcompany.com) isn't combining the CSS & JS (respectively)?

Here are my settings:
Page Cache: Enabled, Disk Enhance
Minify: Enabled, Auto, Disk, Default, JSMin, Default

Comment: Do you mean why isn't it merging them into one file? That wouldn't make sense since they're different content types.

Comment: I meant respective to their languages. If you see the link you'll see that there are numerous CSS files that should be combined into one file. Same with the JS.

Comment: Are you using any other form of minifying or caching?  Did you check the Advanced settings on minification in the W3 Total Cache settings?

Comment: I wasn't at the time I experienced this issue. And yes, I reviewed the Advanced Settings for Minification in W3 Total Cache. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 4):

I use manual disk minify. In my situation w3 total combined JavaScript and CSS. Therefore I recommended to use manual minify (disk). Then go to w3 total minify tab and click on the top "Help" button and add all the necessary js and CSS.

Once added js and/or css remove if there's any queries strings (add js and css direct link) eg:- wp-content/theme/mytheme/style.css

This could break your site. Therefore add js and css step by step.

Comment: So you're suggesting I manually specify each CSS and JS file?

Comment: Yes. It's more reliable

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion. I suppose I'll try it but ultimately I'd like to understand why it's not working presently. I have numerous Plugins that include styles and scripts and manually specifying those is not ideal since we add and remove scripts from time to time.

Comment: If you're worrying about plugin update, it's not an issue (most of the cases). After you place necessary plugin direct link, after the update w3tc automatically detect the new css and js and minify and combined. Yes, after plugin uninstalled you have to manually remove that plugin css and/or js. But it need few minutes. Still i can say manual method more reliable than automatic.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I'm referring to installing new Plugins.

Comment: I would also highly recommend Manual minifying. It may take a little longer depending on the size of your website, and may take some trial & error to know in what order to load the JS/CSS but ultimately your site performance will be better for it :-)